# Positioning a triangle (arrow) element left to text within <td> inside a table using CSS & HTML

Tags: html, css

Working on recreating this table, I'm trying to recreate the triangle position in the first row:

[image]

This part in HTML:

```
<table>
    (...)
    <tr>
        <td><div id="arrowUp"></div>Norrk&ouml;ping</td>
```

Arrow code:

```
#arrowUp {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
    border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}
```

I'm at a loss as how to position this. Tried changing position property but it seems to break the table, margins stretch the  row. It should have something to do with display and position but I'm at a loss with the possibilities and going nowhere blind.

Comment: Use a `<span>`, use a simple [▲ 'BLACK UP-POINTING TRIANGLE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25b2/index.htm) or a [▼ 'BLACK DOWN-POINTING TRIANGLE'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25bc/index.htm) and set the color with a class. Done.

Comment: @LGSon Sadly I can't speak swedish, though I like your country - that's why I'm trying to do something related. Tusen tack :]

Comment: Thought you could, as the table you are using is Swedish football teams :) ... but I see now labels is in English ... My comment says "Added an answer for you"

Answer (score 1):

**▶ 1<sup>st</sup> Option :**

You can achieve this by setting **`position: absolute`** on the **`#arrowUp`** element. Then, you can just play with **`top`** and **`left`** to position the arrow exactly where you want.

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/owo5jphy/4/).

**Snippet:**

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.arrowUp,
.arrowDown {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px;
  position: absolute;  
  left: 8.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
  
.arrowUp {
  border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
  top: 37%;
}

.arrowDown {
  border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
  top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td><div class = "arrowUp"></div>Norrk&ouml;ping</td></tr>
  <tr><td><div class = "arrowDown"></div>AIK</td></tr>
</table>
```

---

**▶ 2<sup>nd</sup> Option :**

While still using the properties mentioned in the 1<sup>st</sup> option, you can get rid of your **`div#arrowUp`** element by setting **`<td class = "arrowUp">Norrk&ouml;ping</td>`** and using the **`:before`** pseudo element. This way you'll use less code while achieving the same result.

**jsFiddle:** → [here](https://jsfiddle.net/owo5jphy/4/).

**Snippet:**

```css
.arrowUp,
.arrowDown {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.arrowUp:before,
.arrowDown:before {
  content: "";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px;
  position: absolute;  
  left: 8.5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
  
.arrowUp:before {
  border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
  top: 37%;
}

.arrowDown:before {
  border-color: #ff0000 transparent transparent transparent;
  top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td class="arrowUp">Norrk&ouml;ping</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="arrowDown">AIK</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `position: absolute`

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
#arrowUp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="arrowUp"></div>Norrk&ouml;ping</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You can solve this without the `div`, using a pseudo element

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
td.arrowUp:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 3px;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 10px 5px;
  border-color: transparent transparent #0dff00 transparent;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="arrowUp">
      Norrk&ouml;ping</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or any of the HTML entity arrows

```css
td {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
td.arrowUp:before {
  content: '⇧';
  position: absolute;
  color: lime;
  left: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="arrowUp">
      Norrk&ouml;ping</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

*Side note: I recommend using a pseudo element instead of an extra element*